# How to map a group within a federated repo to an LDAP group in WebSphere App Server v8.0

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, java-ee-6, rad, websphere-8

I'm able to map LDAP users from Active Directory to an LDAP repository defined within a federated repository in WAS v8.0.0.5.  However, I cannot list any of the Active Directory groups associated with these users.

For instance, when I click on my Security Domain, expand User Realm, and click on "Manage groups" listed under the "Customize for this domain" radio button, I get 0 groups returned.  When I click on "Manage users", I am getting a list of users returned.  Some configuration concerning LDAP groups is wrong, but I don't know where to begin.  Can someone provide me some general pointers as to where/how I should configure LDAP groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution.  The problem was that the groups were defined in a separate major branch, whereas the users I was concerned about were located within another major branch.

Once I set my base entry to a higher level to encompass both major branches, the groups became visible via WAS's admin console.